# How to create new custom field in Add New User view in RefineyCMS

Tags: refinerycms

Can I add new custom field in the Add a New User view in RefineryCMS admin. I login as Superuser I want to create a new user and want to able to associate with a country, I've created a separate extension for adding countries. Pelase help. quite stuck here

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 0):

Hello guys this is how i did it in my application it works 100% .......
you need to override this view[ **view app/views/refinery/admin/users/_form.html.erb** ].
Follow the steps given below

step 1: go to terminal and browse to your project folder and run this command

**rake refinery:override view=refinery/admin/users/_form.html**

**Dont use .erb** this will copy that particular view(that is basically a from partial) related to add_new_user in your
app>views>refinery>admin>user with name _form.html.erb.now you have the page code add any field you want.